# Tooltip description inside parent gets cut off

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get the tooltip description on the top of the data in table. Due to alot of characters present in the tooltip description the tooltip description gets cut off. position of my tool tip is at the top.

Structure

ScrollPanel -> having overflow : auto
-table
-table head
-table data

Setting overflow : visible to the scrollpanel does show the tooltip description properly but the y direction table also overflows:

[image]

Comment: Please share the code

Answer (score 1):

You should check if you are using position property correctly and z-index property also share the code without code its not possible to understand what is causing the issue